# java script i want to add two variables x=y

Tags: javascript

what is the meaning of the following syntax

```
var demoP=document.getElementById("demo");
demoP.innerHTML="x=" + x;
```

and what about this also `"x=" + x;`

Comment: you could have simply run it and found out. waste of electricity

Answer (score 2):

`getElementById()` method accesses the first element with the specified id.

Thus , `document.getElementById("demo")` access the element with the id **demo**.

The `innerHTML`  sets  the inner HTML of an element.It is used to modify your document's HTML on the fly.

For example:

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            var x = 100;
            var demoP = document.getElementById("demo")
            demoP.innerHTML = "x=" + x;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="demo"/>
<p>
    <a href="#" OnClick="myFunction()"> Click to call function</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In above code, when an event is fired by clicking the link,js Method `myFunction()` is called.In this method,demoP contains the element with id **demo**.

demoP.innerHTML modify the demo id and add `x=100` in **demo div**.That is demo div changes to `<div id="demo">x=100</div>`

Answer (score 1):

'x='+x concatenate 'X=' and the value of variable x.

ie; if x=5, then the html element with id 'demo' will now have the content 'x=5'

Comment: /s/will now hold/will contain the html/

Answer (score 1):

It just select an element on the DOM

```
var demoP=document.getElementById("demo")
```

and then it replaces its content with a string

```
demoP.innerHTML="x=" + x;
```

Assuming the value of the x variable is 42 the element (maybe a div?)
will contain the text

```
x=42
```

`"x="+x` just concatenates the two strings: "x=" and x.
If the x content is not a string it will be casted (converted) to a string just before the concatenation (the variable will contains the original value though)

Answer (score 0):

this would set the content of `demo` by concatenation of string, where `"x="` is static part and x is value of variable.

suppose you have follolwing

```
var x = 10;
var demoP=document.getElementById("demo");
demoP.innerHTML="x=" + x;
```

than content of `demo` would be `x=10`